# Using * to dereference custom type implemented Deref trait raise error

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and have been reading *The Rust Programming Language* but stuck at the smart pointer chapter.

With the smart pointer `Box<T>` from Rust stdlib, I can do this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let boxed = Box::new("text".to_string());
    let unboxed = *boxed; // equivalent to `*std::ops::Deref::deref(&boxed)`
    // let unbox_again = *boxed;
    // error: use of moved value *boxed
}
```

And I can see that using `*` to dereference a pointer will make the ownership move.

Then I followed the *Define your own smart pointer* example from the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#defining-our-own-smart-pointer), here's my code:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

struct MyBox<T> {
    value: T
}

impl<T> MyBox<T> {
    fn new(x: T) -> Self {
        MyBox { value: x }
    }
}

impl<T> Deref for MyBox<T>  {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
       &self.value 
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_boxed = MyBox::new("string".to_string());
    let my_unboxed = *my_boxed;
    // error: move occurs here
}
```

I tried the same as with the first example, but I got error when I tried using `*` to dereference `MyBox<T>`.

So what's the problem with `MyBox<T>`?

I know that `Box<T>` pointer actually stores data on the heap while `MyBox<T>` not. Is it something related to this?

Comment: Good question; unfortunately, the answer turns out to just be "because `Box` is special". It's not particularly related to heap storage (although the *reason* `Box` is special is because it started life as Rust's unique heap pointer type `~T`).

Comment: I'd like to second @trentcl. This is why you see so many `into_inner()` methods on pointers that don't have the `Box` special-cased syntax. When you use `*` to dereference a `Box`, it can either act like `*(box.as_mut())` (same as any normal `AsMut` pointer), or it can act like a hypothetical `box.into_inner()`. The compiler chooses which one based on type inferences.